# React Native - button position in center of footer

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I would like to put my button (TouchableOpacity) in the bottom of the page as a footer and horizontally aligned with a width of 250.

My code so far:

https://snack.expo.io/SkbWUWm1M

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pujdD.png)

Comment: Dont really get your problem. Maybe this helps you. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp 
Maybe you should add more information to your question

Comment: Please further explain your issue, it is not clear.

Comment: I added my code to a link. Basically, I want the button to be always on the bottom of the page and centered horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

use 
    margin-left: instead of left